# OneAPI: Possible to statically link libraries with DPC++/OneAPI for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, intel-oneapi, dpc++

I've just installed the Intel compiler for Visual Studio. Under the DPC++ project settings->Code Generation the only option is Multi-Threaded DLL.

Searching high and low on the internet yielded no information.

Does this toolset only support dynamic linking?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the only option present as of now in Visual Studio IDE. Please find the below link:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/oneapi-dpcpp-cpp-compiler-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/linking-or-linker-options/ld.html